# Sitecore Commerce 9 high availability guidelines

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I'm looking for official documentation or community guidelines for provisioning a highly available production installation of Sitecore Commerce 9.*.

So far haven't been able to find much online or on the official documentation apart from a generic mention that Azure tools can be used for PaaS installations.

In my entirely theoretical scenario, a business would rely solely on their commerce capabilities so downtime of commerce features would not be acceptable.

To meet such requirement I suppose the Shared Environments database would need mirroring and a physically and logically separate instance of commerce would need to be on stand-by, possibly cross-region. That's as far as my understanding goes.

However, how exactly should that be implemented?

What types of mirroring/replication are supported? How would the minions handle the failover?

Those are the types of answers I'd be curious to read about.

Answer (score 0):

To address the scaling of different apps, you can get an idea of how to roll out a basic PaaS production topology by referencing the documentation for tiers on the Knowledge Base site: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/748063

Those are for a very specific scenario, assuming CDN for static assets like images, and also for minimum size to achieve pass rates. You will most likely need to adjust based on your specific implementation, but it is supposed to give you an idea of where to start and where to scale as visits go up.

This does not document things like mirroring or failover, it is assumed that you are using the standard Azure high availability for PaaS apps.

(While I know link-only answers are frowned upon, in this case the amount documented there does not make sense to copy over. )

Comment: That's useful Jason. It sorts out scaling of different apps on PaaS. It doesn't address scenarios (PaaS and on-prem) where mirroring and failover are potentially required.